# Using a "Local" namespace in xml

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

Is there a term or standard for using local namespaces in an XML document? For example, I'd like to separate a display item of `Rows` and `Columns` and so I am simply doing:

```
<Data xmlns:R="Rows" xmlns:C="Columns" xmlns:V="Values">
    <R:ProductGroup value="Electronics">
        <R:Product value="Computer">
            <C:Year value="2018">
                <V:SumOfRevenue value="104" />
                <V:SumOfUnits value="3" />
            </C:Year>
            <C:Year value="2019">
                <V:SumOfRevenue value="82" />
                <V:SumOfUnits value="9" />
            </C:Year>
            <C:Year value="(all)">
                <V:SumOfRevenue value="186" />
                <V:SumOfUnits value="12" />
            </C:Year>
        </R:Product>
    </R:ProductGroup>
</Data>
```

This is much simpler than mangling the names such as "Rows_Product", etc. but I was wondering what the practice is for using a 'local' namespace that doesn't mean anything outside of the current document and if that is a common practice (and if so, what suggestions are supposed to be followed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "local" namespaces in XML. There are namspaces. And you can create as many of them as you want, where you want. Some of them are widely recognized (such as the ones for XSLT or XHTML), some of them are not. Technically they all are equal.

But the purpose of namespaces is to separate nodes that belong to different domains, in order to prevent name clashes (which makes XML composable) and to make nodes of a given domain easy to select and process (e.g. `//xhtml:*` would select all XHTML nodes).

What you're trying to do here is merge data with display semantics, and that's not a terribly good idea, no matter if you do it using namespaces or "mangled" names.

Your data is this

```
<Data>
    <ProductGroup value="Electronics">
        <Product value="Computer">
            <Year value="2018">
                <SumOfRevenue value="104" />
                <SumOfUnits value="3" />
            </Year>
            <Year value="2019">
                <SumOfRevenue value="82" />
                <SumOfUnits value="9" />
            </Year>
            <Year value="(all)">
                <SumOfRevenue value="186" />
                <SumOfUnits value="12" />
            </Year>
        </Product>
    </ProductGroup>
</Data>
```

Don't preempt in the XML-structure which of those items should be displayed as rows or columns, those things have nothing to do with each other. You don't want to have to re-write your XML just because somebody decided that the table should now be displayed horizontally instead of vertically, or that it should become a list.

Let the XML transport the data, let the view component of your application sort out how it would be best to display it.

Comment: Technically, there are namespaces and non-namespaces; the elements in this example technically have names that are in no namespace. It's often called the "null namespace", but that's technically incorrect because it's not actually a namespace. I sometimes call it the "non-namespace", but it doesn't really have a name because it doesn't really exist...

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces weren't designed to be used in the way you are using them. It's much simpler with this kind of document either to avoid using namespaces altogether, or to put everything in the same namespace with an xmlns="...." declaration at the top.